# Easy As LITS: Lots of "S"s

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is an Easy as LITS puzzle (LITS variation), where you shade cells to form tetrominoes

Rules taken from [Grandmaster Puzzles](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2014/11/easy-lits-prasanna-seshadri-3/):

- Shade exactly four connected cells in each outlined region, to form an L, I, T, or S tetromino.
- All shaded cells are connected with each other.
- No 2×2 group of cells can be entirely shaded black.
- When two tetrominoes in adjacent regions share an edge, they must not be of the same type (L, I, T, or S), regardless of rotations or reflections.
- The letters outside the grid indicate the first tetromino encountered in the corresponding direction.

An example puzzle and its solution, taken from Grandmaster Puzzles (who in turn credit Chris Green):

[image: example]

Now, solve this puzzle:

[image: the real puzzle]

*Note: if you want to solve this on the image, clickthrough to get the full size version*

First answer with a fully-explained logical solution path gets the checkmark.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a few regions can be assigned shapes:

> S must go in all three of the top regions.
>  [image]
>  And then L must go in the right region.
>  [image]

Now, the break-in:

> **Where is the L seen by column 3?**
>  It can be either in the center region, the left region, or the bottom left. If in the bottom left, we can't satisfy the S; if in the left, then we can't connect to the top left S. So it must be in the center.
>
>  [image]

And now we can resolve most of the grid:

> Note that the S in the top right can't connect left. This means it must go down and around. And in each of the regions, there's only one way we can place a piece to extend the shaded cells.
>  [image]

And with some connectivity arguments, the puzzle is solved:

> The left region cannot connect the bottom to the top; it would have to use an L, and then there's no way we could attach the L in the middle region.
>  So the top-left region must go down and to the *right*, which places the L; finally, a T in the left region finishes off the puzzle.
>  [image]